# Masonry jQuery plugin and empty spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I am thinking of using [Masonry plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com) in one of my projects. What I wonder about if it's possible some way to detect empty spaces that sometimes appear in the layout when divs are positioned. If I had a way to check such blank spaces, I could fill them with some generated divs with some data in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would play with offset().left. For example:

1. Store a masonry item in variable "item"
2. Check if item.next().offset().left equals item.offset().left+item.outerWidth(true)

That will check if the item next to our starting item is actually *there*. Note that outerWidth(true) makes sure the margin between items is also counted.

Hope my theory makes sense to you,
Good luck.